# Unreadable json POST request

Tags: json, api, request

I'm trying to reverse an api with mitmproxy. The Problem is, that the login request has an obfuscated/encoded json body. Does anyone know how to decode/deobfuscate this? I've tried to login with the following credentials.

USERNAME:test
PASSWORD:test

Header:

```
POST https://davincigameserver.appspot.com/api/user/quizduel/login HTTP/2.0
accept: */*
x-davinci-gzip-compression: True
content-type:   application/json
accept-language:    de-de
x-unity-version:    2019.4.15f1
payload-session:    DEBF9B60E68BDB628FB480806FD45DFD
user-agent: Ios/New QuizDuel/1.14.4
content-length: 448
accept-encoding:    br, gzip, deflate
```

JSON:

```
\xbb\x8c(\x04\x87\x99\xf8i\xfeX\xde\xd8\x10\xfb\xb70 a\x8d|R\xd3\xa3\xec(c\xa7"JE'\xca[\x90\x08\xf6\xaf\xecD\xa4KM\x11\xc3\x89\x17\x04\xdf\xc7dU\xcfD\xef-\xcb\xb0\xbd \x10\x98/\x8a\xc7\xac \xe3\xd8\xc9\xa5\xf2c]\xeb&\x83,   \xed\x12\xc8\xd5\x02\xb7m&\x81\xdcV\xbb\xc5\x02\xfa|$\xd2\xb8\xfe2\x8c\xcd(\x1aJh\x0el\x85\x0fi{\xee_\xc8\xe5`\xd3\x15\x90\xbe\xd7\xc6\x8f\x8e/\xc3\xb6zK\xa9(U\x06\xc1isy\x8a\x1e\xeb\x10\xcbu#\xf1 ?\xd2\xc2\x9f+\x92r\x1c\xf9<\xd656\xd4\xbb\xbc\xe2\xfc\xaa*\xfc}W_Po\xbb\x195;ye\xa7\xffwN\x95b=\xfe\xc5U\xba\xf2\x84\xa2\x1dP1z\x19z\x1d(\x87\x86\xe8u\xdfsO\x8d\x96\xc4\xe6F>\x83?\x01\xb9\xd4\x90\x8d\x8f9\xf2\xb4\x05
R\x8b\xd6\x12\x95h\xad\x00>Q\x82\x9b}$\xf7k\xb0
Iu\xba\xe2\xee\xeb\xf06\x02\xa4\xf4\x10#\x0c\xf5h:\xfaP\xc6\xe7\xda\xdb\x8ct\x12"\x96u\x85\xa2[\xf8\xf8K\xbfQE'e\xbf\x18\xe3\xbc\xa3\xf5\xe0G<FM\x14\xaf\x8ck$\x10\xb2\xf2bO\x8b\xf7\x82e&\x92\xc0\xddz}k1\xafV\xc4\xb1m\xe3\xa3\xdcb\xa9\x13\xc6?~\xe5\x94\xd2\xb1\x84\x01\x9c\x01\x97\xaal\xc04\xfd\x01\x88\xcf\x04s>A\xcacu\xbc\xa0\x97S\x9a\x06\x05\x91\xdc\xdb\xf7\xf9\xc3z2\xf2\x94\xad\x0e\x1d\x98\xf1?\x11\xd7\xbf\xe9\xfb\xbe\x8d\xa3\xee\x11\xd2K&\x18\x83\xb9\xbc<\x03D8\x92\xf8\x0f\xf0t\xf9[kC\xd1\xc5\xc9jF\xc93\xb7\xb8\xe84\xee_\xac\xf8'e\x94|>Z\x7f\xacB\xc3q\xfd
L0\xc3\xca\x0b\x9f\xc3C65\x19\x9d
```